# Why is my asp .net updatePanel timer refreshing the entire page?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, timer, refresh, updatepanel

I have a page which displays particular controls based on a set of checks in preload and load methods.

I have an update panel in which should display the contents of a file whilst it is being written to. I do this by having a timer in the updatepanel and a textbox. The plan is to update the textbox with file contents on each tick of the timer.

Now as far as i understand it from this; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx I should be able to just update the textbox in the updatepanel without a entire page refresh but i see my page_load being hit, why?

My code

```
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePnlStatusScreen" runat="server" Visible="False">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Timer ID="timerLogFileOutput" runat="server" Enabled="False" Interval="5000" ontick="timerLogOutput_Tick">
                    </asp:Timer>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbLogOutputScreen" runat="server" Height="50%" Width="100%">Nothing logged yet...</asp:TextBox>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update panel will activate postback and the full page life cycle (Page_Load and everything), the difference is only in the rendering - update panel will cause only partial rendering. You should wrap the code you don't want to run on postback inside a `if (IsPostBack==false) { .. }`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set childrenastriggers to false and updatemode=conditional

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePnlStatusScreen" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" UpdateMode="Conditional" style="display:none">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer ID="timerLogFileOutput" runat="server" Enabled="False" Interval="5000" ontick="timerLogOutput_Tick">
                </asp:Timer>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbLogOutputScreen" runat="server" Height="50%" Width="100%">Nothing logged yet...</asp:TextBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```